# First print works but second time blank page prints

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a windows app i built that has 5 tabs. On 2 of the tabs i give the option to print only if the datagridview.rowcount is greater than 0. This will allow the print button to appear. I can print the first report just fine, but if i select different parameters and repopulate the datagridview again or move to the other tab and populate its datagridview and try to print i only get blank pages for every time after the first print job. Any thought on why?

Here is All Code

```
    Dim strFormat As New StringFormat()
    Dim arrColumnLefts, arrColumnWidths As New ArrayList()
    Dim iCellHeight, iTotalWidth, iCount, iLeftMargin, iTopMargin, iTmpWidth, iHeaderHeight, iRow As Integer
    Dim bFirstPage, bNewPage, bMorePagesToPrint As Boolean
    Dim dgvGridCol, GridCol As DataGridViewColumn
    Dim GridRow As DataGridViewRow

    Public Sub btn_print_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_print.Click

        If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            PrintDocument1.DocumentName = "Report Printing"
            PrintDocument1.Print()
        End If
    End Sub

    'Handles the begin print event of print document
    Public Sub printDocument1_BeginPrint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
        Try
            strFormat = New StringFormat()
            strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
            strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
            arrColumnLefts.Clear()
            arrColumnWidths.Clear()
            iCellHeight = 0
            iCount = 0
            bFirstPage = True
            bNewPage = True
            iTotalWidth = 0
            If TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = "Reports" Then
                For Each dgvGridCol As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView4.Columns
                    iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width
                Next
            ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = "Stats" Then
                For Each dgvGridCol As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                    iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
        End Try
    End Sub


    'Handles the print page event of print document
    Public Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        If TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = "Reports" Then
            Try
                'Set the left margin
                Dim iLeftMargin As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Left
                'Set the top margin
                Dim iTopMargin As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Top
                'Whether more pages have to print
                Dim bMorePagesToPrint As Boolean = False
                Dim iTmpWidth As Integer = 0
                'For the first page to print, set the cell width and header height 
                If bFirstPage Then
                    For Each GridCol As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView4.Columns
                        iTmpWidth = CInt((Math.Floor(CDbl((CDbl(GridCol.Width) / CDbl(iTotalWidth) * CDbl(iTotalWidth) * (CDbl(e.MarginBounds.Width) / CDbl(iTotalWidth)))))))
                        iHeaderHeight = CInt((e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height)) + 11
                        arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin)
                        arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth)
                        iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth
                    Next
                End If
                'Loop until all the grid rows get printed
                While iRow <= DataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim GridRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView4.Rows(iRow)
                    'Set the cell height
                    iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5
                    Dim iCount As Integer = 0
                    'Check whether the current page settings allows more rows to print
                    If iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top Then
                        bNewPage = True
                        bFirstPage = False
                        bMorePagesToPrint = True
                        Exit While
                    Else
                        If bNewPage Then
                            'Draw header
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)
                            If CheckedListBox5.SelectedItem = "Multi" Then
                                Dim strDateMulti As String = report_start.Value.ToLongDateString() & "  -  " + report_end.Value.Date.ToLongDateString()
                                'Draw Date For Multi-Day Report
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(strDateMulti, New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDateMulti, New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)
                            ElseIf CheckedListBox5.SelectedItem = "Daily" Then
                                Dim strDateDaily As String = report_start.Value.ToLongDateString()
                                'Draw Date For Daily Report
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(strDateDaily, New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDateDaily, New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString(UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(New Font(DataGridView4.Font, FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)
                            End If
                            'Draw Columns
                            iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top
                            For Each GridCol As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView4.Columns
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), New Rectangle(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iHeaderHeight))
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iHeaderHeight))
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iHeaderHeight), strFormat)
                                iCount += 1
                            Next
                            bNewPage = False
                            iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight
                        End If
                        iCount = 0
                        'Draw Column contents
                        For Each Cel As DataGridViewCell In GridRow.Cells
                            If Cel.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), CSng(iTopMargin), CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), CSng(iCellHeight)), strFormat)
                            End If
                            'Drawing Cell Borders
                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iCellHeight))
                            iCount += 1
                        Next
                    End If
                    iRow += 1
                    iTopMargin += iCellHeight
                End While
                'If more lines exist, print another page
                If bMorePagesToPrint Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                Else
                    e.HasMorePages = False
                End If
            Catch exc As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
            End Try
            'PRINT STATS TAB
        ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = "Stats" Then
            Try
                'Set the left margin
                Dim iLeftMargin As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Left
                'Set the top margin
                Dim iTopMargin As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Top
                'Whether more pages have to print
                Dim bMorePagesToPrint As Boolean = False
                Dim iTmpWidth As Integer = 0
                'For the first page to print, set the cell width and header height 
                If bFirstPage Then
                    For Each GridCol As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                        iTmpWidth = CInt((Math.Floor(CDbl((CDbl(GridCol.Width) / CDbl(iTotalWidth) * CDbl(iTotalWidth) * (CDbl(e.MarginBounds.Width) / CDbl(iTotalWidth)))))))
                        iHeaderHeight = CInt((e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height)) + 11
                        arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin)
                        arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth)
                        iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth
                    Next
                End If
                'Loop until all the grid rows get printed
                While iRow <= DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim GridRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(iRow)
                    'Set the cell height
                    iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5
                    Dim iCount As Integer = 0
                    'Check whether the current page settings allows more rows to print
                    If iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top Then
                        bNewPage = True
                        bFirstPage = False
                        bMorePagesToPrint = True
                        Exit While
                    Else
                        If bNewPage Then
                            If CheckedListBox3.SelectedItem = "All" And CheckedListBox2.SelectedItem = "Department" Then
                                'Draw header for ALL-Department
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("(" + UCase(txt_ID.Text).ToString() & ") " + UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)
                            ElseIf CheckedListBox3.SelectedItem = "All" And CheckedListBox2.SelectedItem = "AssociateID" Then
                                'Draw header for ALL -ID
                                e.Graphics.DrawString("(" + UCase(txt_ID.Text).ToString() & ") " + UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("(" + UCase(txt_ID.Text).ToString() & ") " + UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)
                            ElseIf CheckedListBox3.SelectedItem = "Sum" And CheckedListBox2.SelectedItem = "AssociateID" Then
                                'Draw header SUM -ID
                                e.Graphics.DrawString("(" + UCase(txt_ID.Text).ToString() & ") " + UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("(" + UCase(txt_ID.Text).ToString() & ") " + UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)
                            ElseIf CheckedListBox3.SelectedItem = "Sum" And CheckedListBox2.SelectedItem = "Department" Then
                                'Draw header SUM -Dept
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("(" + UCase(txt_ID.Text).ToString() & ") " + UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)

                            End If
                            'Draw Date
                            Dim strDate As String = start_stat.Value.ToLongDateString() & "  -  " + end_stat.Value.Date.ToLongDateString()
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("(" + UCase(txt_ID.Text).ToString() & ") " + UCase(txt_DeptCode.Text).ToString() & "  -  " + UCase(txt_OpCode.Text).ToString(), New Font(New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13)


                            'Draw Columns
                            iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top
                            For Each GridCol As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.LightGray), New Rectangle(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iHeaderHeight))
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iHeaderHeight))
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iHeaderHeight), strFormat)
                                iCount += 1
                            Next
                            bNewPage = False
                            iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight
                        End If
                        iCount = 0
                        'Draw Column contents
                        For Each Cel As DataGridViewCell In GridRow.Cells
                            If Cel.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor), New RectangleF(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), CSng(iTopMargin), CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), CSng(iCellHeight)), strFormat)
                            End If
                            'Drawing Cell Borders
                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)), iTopMargin, CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)), iCellHeight))
                            iCount += 1
                        Next
                    End If
                    iRow += 1
                    iTopMargin += iCellHeight
                End While
                'If more lines exist, print another page
                If bMorePagesToPrint Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                Else
                    e.HasMorePages = False
                End If
            Catch exc As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
            End Try

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry that bothers you @Ken White. I am just trying to give as much as i can so that it may better help someone provide a solution.

Comment: I have update the post and removed the clutter and added the `PrintPage` code

Comment: Where does `iRow` come from, and where is it initialized before you use it in `while iRow <= DataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1`?

Comment: It is contained inside the form class. I added the code above

Comment: You have double declarations.  iCount is declared at the form level, and then you declare it again in the print method.  Don't do that.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? I'll wager not. You should never post a question here without having debugged thoroughly first. Place a breakpoint at the top of the `PrintPage` event handler and then step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step and comparing that state to what you expect. The reason for your issue should become fairly obvious if you do that.  Most likely `iRow` is not being reset but you'd never know if you don't debug properly.